# Intercept all the Spam messages in Gmail before they're delivered to Spam folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

I want to filter out some specific (many conditions) messages that are (ultimately) stored in *Spam* folder in Gmail. However, [according to this article](https://onezeronull.com/2023/06/16/use-deliveredto-gmail-filter-to-capture-non-typical-spam/) I cannot use `in:spam`, `is:spam` or `label:spam` filter conditions because filters containing such condition supposedly never match any incoming messages.

[image]

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Is there any other way (using message filters in Gmail) to "intercept" all emails that Gmail thinks are spam (and is going to deliver them to *Spam* folder) before they're actually sent to *Spam* folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, You Can't

- You can't filter incoming messages based on Gmail ultimately labeling them as SPAM.
- You can filter incoming messages based on other conditions and have them excluded from SPAM.
- You can filter incoming messages based on other criteria and have them labeled as SPAM.

#### Apps Script

Your only option is to run a Google Apps Script every few minutes to identify messages in your SPAM folder that meet other criteria and then perform an action on them.